# Why does this sql query not work in pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i'm trying to retrieve info from my database using PDO.

The code i'm using is

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

$inputvalue = $_GET['inputvalue'];

$db = DB::get_instance();
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM hwidex7 WHERE :input=:inputvalue');
$query->bindParam(':inputvalue', $inputvalue);
$query->bindParam(':input', $input);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I am really sorry of my grammar, i hope someone who understands me can edit my question so its more understandable

Comment: Why use quotes at all on HWID?

Comment: Someone needs to go read up on some basics ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: I've edited the question hoping that it makes more sense now

Comment: You can't bind a column name to a value like you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind table or column as parameter in PDO

You can build your query as

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hwidex7 WHERE `$input` =:inputvalue");
$query->bindParam(':inputvalue', $inputvalue);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Just have to be really careful with that $input variable

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$input' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is `$input` contain your column name??

Comment: Yes, i put one of my column names in there

Comment: What is the value of `$input` ??

Comment: The value of $input is a GET value, for testing i've used HWID

Comment: I've fixed it by doing it like this
`$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM hwidex7 WHERE '.$input.' =:inputvalue');`

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM hwidex7 WHERE `HWID`='3087793810'
```

Just try above query.

You will get Idea for same.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what i mean, i've added my code so you might understand what i mean.